# iterating through dictionary in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, tableview

this might be a common situation, but I was not able to figure out a way how to do it.

I have a dictionary with the stock amount for several items: `dict = ["item1" : 2, "item2" : 5, "item3" : 10 ]`

How can I now assign the keys and values to different labels in a tableView, using `indexPath`?

The logic I want to achieve:

```
cell.itemLabel.text = dict.[firstItemName]
cell.amountLabel.text = dict.[firstItemAmount]
```

Comment: You might want to use an array of struct or `KeyValuePairs`. dictionary is unordered.

Answer (score 2):

A dictionary as data source can be annoying because a dictionary is unordered.

My suggestion is to `map` the dictionary to an array of a custom struct and sort the array by the *keys*

```
struct Model {
    let name : String
    let value: Int
}

let dict = ["item1" : 2, "item2" : 5, "item3" : 10 ]

let array = dict.map(Model.init).sorted{$0.name < $1.name}
```

Then in the table view you can write

```
cell.itemLabel.text = array[indexPath.row].name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map function to get separate array of key and values

```
print(dict.map({$0.key}))
print(dict.map({$0. value}))
```

Try this:

```
cell.itemLabel.text = dict.map({$0.key})[indexPath.row]
cell.amountLabel.text = dict.map({$0.value})[indexPath.row]
```